# Routing Angular js 2 error for URL : http:localhost:4200/project/file-(Inside-Parenthesis)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, routes

```
    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Inside-Parenthesis'
    Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Inside-Parenthesis'
  at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.js:149) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (apply_redirects.js:118) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
```

url looks like `http:localhost:4200/project/text-(Inside-Parenthesis)`

I am not using auxiliary route

`http:localhost:4200/project/text-Inside-Parenthesis`, works fine but my data comes in with Parenthesis.

Comment: i'm not sure what you wanna do, i guess you wanna using `Route Parameters`

Comment: `http:localhost:4200/project/file-:idfile`, where idfile is a param, it's dynamically pass some way

Comment: @TiepPhan i am using route parameters and "text-Inside-Parenthesis" is a parameter that i am passing but if a parameter has parenthesis then it is throwing the above exception

Comment: ah, this is a bug in angular, please try this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280

Comment: hmm thanks @TiepPhan